# Integral of $xe^{-ax^2-bx^{-1}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function

I am currently facing an integral I have no clue how to solve it. I believe it is rather exoctic, but I hope you might have some good advice:

$$\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-ax^2-bx^{-1}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
$$ a,b\in\mathbb{C},\,\, \Re(b)=0,\,\,\Im(b)\in\left[-\infty,+\infty\right], \,\,a\neq0$$
As my knowledge is about of a science undergraduate student I tried sofar subsitutions, expansion to the complex numbers (integration of an analytic function), partial integration. Also I have tried to solve it by reshaping it in various ways and looking for a solution in the book "Table of Integrals, Series, And Products".

I need to understand the integration, so the answer alone won't help me very much. That is why I would like to know how your strategy on solving it would be, and what advice you can give me. The actual solving I need and want to do by myself.

Thank you for your help

If anything is unclear please let me know (english is not my best language)

Comment: Is that supposd to be $x^{-1}$ in the exponent?

Comment: Tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I have tried various substitutions and partial integration, if you could suggest other strategies, please give me the names so I can read them up

Comment: No I didn't try Wolfram Alpha yet

Comment: Are you sure there's a nice answer? Because on WA the computation times out: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+x+e%5E%7B-x%5E2-x%5E%7B-1%7D%7D

Comment: This is just the key integral in a pretty long equation, so the final result looks nicer (according to numerical results almost like a gaussian)

Comment: $$\frac{b^2 G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{a b^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,-\frac{1}{2},0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{8 \sqrt{\pi }},\Re(b)>0\land \Re(a)>0$$ Where G is the Meijer G function. I hope this is good enough for you

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you just briefly explain what exactly you did to get this result, so I can calculate it myself and understand it?

Comment: I don't understand it either. This is what mathematica bestowed upon us in its infinite wisdom.

Comment: For $ab\neq0$, it can be expressed in terms of the [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function), but that's about it.

Comment: I am trying to contour integrate it myself. *Maybe* there is a nicer form. I don't count on myself though.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help, if I find a solution by myself I will let you know!

Comment: Maple also produces a Meijer G answer.  With $a=b=1$ it is numerically 0.15004596450516388137679 which is not recognized by ISC.